# np.polyval to np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I don't understand how I can migrate np.polyval to np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval. Because of the reversal of coefficient order, I account for this with [::-1] and there still is an issue plotting.

1- Creating a function to plot later

```
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x) + 0.5 * x
```

```
x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 50)
```

Using old method, it works:

```
old_polyfit =np.polyfit(x, f(x), 1)
old_polyval = np.polyval(old_polyfit , x)

plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b', label='f(x)')
plt.plot(x, old_polyval, 'r.', label='regression')
```

My problem: I use the new method and there are two issues,

1-

```
new_polyfit =np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, f(x), 1)
new_polyval = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(new_polyfit[::-1], x)
```

I see that New_polfit does not math the inverse of old_polyfit, which it should from coef order change..

2- Plotting with the new_polyval = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(new_polyfit[::-1], x)

error -->  1) plt.plot(x, new_polyval, 'r.', label='regression')
2) x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (2,)

```
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b', label='f(x)')
plt.plot(x, new_polyval, 'r.', label='regression')
```

I don't understand why the old_polyval would size (50,) while newpolyval is (2,).

Comment: it should be ```new_polyval = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, new_polyfit)``` then the two figures are the same

Comment: Thank you. Why is old_polyfit (2,) [.4288,-1.402] versus the new_polyfit (2,)[-2.552,.4288]..I would expect them to be a1,a2 and the other a2,a1?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what is old_polyfit (2,) ?

Comment: Why is the old polyfit not the reverse of the new polyfit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new poly packages not only reverses the order of the coefficients, it also reverses the order of the arguments.  Once you started to get errors, did you go back and read the docs?

your function:

```
In [305]: def f(x):
     ...:     return np.sin(x) + 0.5 * x
     ...: 
     ...: x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 50)
```

the old fit:

```
In [308]: old_polyfit =np.polyfit(x, f(x), 1)
     ...: old_polyval = np.polyval(old_polyfit , x)

In [309]: old_polyfit
Out[309]: array([ 4.28841952e-01, -7.45793918e-17])

In [310]: old_polyval
Out[310]: 
array([-2.69449345, -2.58451412, -2.4745348 , -2.36455548, -2.25457615,
       -2.14459683, -2.0346175 , -1.92463818, -1.81465885, -1.70467953,
       -1.5947002 , ...,  2.14459683,
        2.25457615,  2.36455548,  2.4745348 ,  2.58451412,  2.69449345])
```

Your new try:

```
In [311]: new_polyfit =np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, f(x), 1)
     ...: new_polyval = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(new_polyfit[::-1], x)

In [312]: new_polyfit
Out[312]: array([-1.88411095e-16,  4.28841952e-01])

In [313]: new_polyval
Out[313]: array([-10.66365141,  -6.28318531])
```

The switch in the coefficients order is clear; why the switch?  That's for the developers to explain.

Reading the docs I see the new `polyval` expects the `(x,c)` order:

```
In [317]: 
     ...: new_polyval = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, new_polyfit)

In [318]: new_polyval
Out[318]: 
array([-2.69449345, -2.58451412, -2.4745348 , -2.36455548, -2.25457615,
       -2.14459683, -2.0346175 , -1.92463818, -1.81465885, -1.70467953,
       -1.5947002 , ...  2.14459683,
        2.25457615,  2.36455548,  2.4745348 ,  2.58451412,  2.69449345])
```

these match the old.

We could also use the newfit values with the old `val`, by just reversing the coeff.

```
In [320]: old_polyval = np.polyval(new_polyfit[::-1] , x)

In [321]: old_polyval
Out[321]: 
array([-2.69449345, -2.58451412, -2.4745348 , -2.36455548, -2.25457615,
       -2.14459683, -2.0346175 , -1.92463818, -1.81465885, -1.70467953,
       -1.5947002 , ... 2.14459683,
        2.25457615,  2.36455548,  2.4745348 ,  2.58451412,  2.69449345])
```

Comment: Why is the old polyfit not the reverse of the new polyfit as you showed via polyval? Thank you.

Comment: It is close - the `e-16` values are practically 0.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. You're right, it is close. I'll have to keep this example in mind moving forward if there are future differences on this operation. Thanks for your helpful comments.